# Outlook rest api ErrorNonExistentMailbox

Tags: outlook-api

I am getting ErrorNonExistentMailbox error when sending a draft email from user's account. Its happening to a single user.

{"error":{"code":"ErrorNonExistentMailbox","message":"The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it."}}

What can be the reason behind this?